# Sklearn.mixture.dpgmm not functioning correctly

Tags: scikit-learn

I'm having trouble with sklearn.mixture.dpgmm. The main issue is that it is not returning correct covariances for synthetic data (2 separated 2D gaussians), where it really should have no issue. In particular, when I do dpgmm._get_covars(), the covariance matrices have diagonal elements that are always exactly 1.0 too large, regardless of the input data distributions. This seems like a bug, as gmm works perfectly (when limiting to known exact number of groups)

Another issue is that dpgmm.weights_ makes no sense, they sum to one but the values appear meaningless.

Does anyone have a solution to this or see something clearly wrong with my example?

Here is the exact script I'm running:

```
import itertools
import numpy as np
from scipy import linalg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import pdb

from sklearn import mixture

# Generate 2D random sample, two gaussians each with 10000 points
rsamp1 =     np.random.multivariate_normal(np.array([5.0,5.0]),np.array([[1.0,-0.2],[-0.2,1.0]]),10000)
rsamp2 = np.random.multivariate_normal(np.array([0.0,0.0]),np.array([[0.2,-0.0],[-0.0,3.0]]),10000)
X = np.concatenate((rsamp1,rsamp2),axis=0)

# Fit a mixture of Gaussians with EM using 2
gmm = mixture.GMM(n_components=2, covariance_type='full',n_iter=10000)
gmm.fit(X)

# Fit a Dirichlet process mixture of Gaussians using 10 components
dpgmm = mixture.DPGMM(n_components=10, covariance_type='full',min_covar=0.5,tol=0.00001,n_iter = 1000000)
dpgmm.fit(X)

print("Groups With data in them")
print(np.unique(dpgmm.predict(X)))

##print the input and output covars as example, should be very similar
correct_c0 = np.array([[1.0,-0.2],[-0.2,1.0]])
print "Input covar"
print correct_c0

covars = dpgmm._get_covars()
c0 = np.round(covars[0],decimals=1)
print "Output Covar"
print c0

print("Output Variances Too Big by 1.0")
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [dpgmm docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.DPGMM.html) this Class is **Deprecated** in version 0.18 and will be removed in version 0.20

You should use [BayesianGaussianMixture](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.BayesianGaussianMixture.html) Class instead, with parameter `weight_concentration_prior_type` set with option `"dirichlet_process"`

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

instead of writing

```
from sklearn.mixture import GMM
gmm = GMM(2, covariance_type='full', random_state=0)
```

you should write:

```
from sklearn.mixture import BayesianGaussianMixture
gmm = BayesianGaussianMixture(2, covariance_type='full', random_state=0)
```